# Showing warning while printing the numerical value stored in scope using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

As I am trying to print the numerical value through input tag which is stored in the scope using angularjs,I am getting a warning like this:
"The specified value "**{{mobile}}**" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?"
and in the input tag I have given like this:

note:strings are getting printed.only problem with numerical value.
Please help me out.

Comment: How did you used regular expression?

Comment: Would you please specify the input type and AngularJS variable declaration type ? What Angular version u are using ? Would u please past the code ?

Answer (score 0):

you can input only numerical value only
like a javascript code:
 = 48 && event.charCode <= 57" ng-model="user.userMobile"  />